# android service find view from another application

Tags: android, service

I want to write a service for finding a view such as `EditText` from another application.
For example finding EditText of native phone SMS Application to extract user typed message before composing it.
In Windows programming ,WIN API functions (FindWindow) Exist , In Android how ?
thank you.

Comment: I believe you are not allowed to do so. You can't interact with other application like that. That would be like security/privacy breach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible...  Android sandboxes applications from each other, and applications must explicity share resources.  If you did find a way to do this (on a non-rooted phone) it would be considered a security breach.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html